# Camera controls in Zbar

Tags: ios, zbar-sdk

Hi I am trying to show camera controls using zbar in ios for scanning.

i have written following code

```
ZBarReaderViewController *readerController = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
readerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
readerController.tracksSymbols = YES;
readerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
readerController.showsZBarControls = YES;
[readerController release];
```

But application crash every time when i show zbar controller.

and app work fine if i remove this line

```
readerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

But then i can not see any control on scan view

Answer (score 0):

"BOOL showsCameraControls Raises an exception if anything other than NO is set."
Check the following link for details: [ZBarReaderViewController Class Reference](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarReaderViewController.html). Cheers